# Matlab bar plot grouped but in different y scales

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two sets of data, and I want to plot using bar graph. But the problem is these two sets of data are at quite different scale. If I just use the `bar(A)`, it would look like this: grouped but the second data set is barely visible because the scale.

[image]

However, if I use the `plotyy(x,y1,x,y2)`, the plot will be like this: two sets of data are in different scale, but the bar graphs are not grouped, the second data sets overlaps to the first.

[image]

So I am wondering if there is a way to plot the bar graph grouped like the first figure, but the two datasets are using separate y scales? Or is there a way to adjust the horizontal offset of the bar graph in second plot so it looks like "grouped".

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses the `plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2,fun1,fun2)` variant of [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html):

```
%// Set these three variables as desired
offset = (x(2)-x(1))/8;
width = (x(2)-x(1))/4;
colors = {'b','g'};

%// Do the plot
plotyy(x-offset,y1,x+offset,y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{1}), @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{2}));
```

[image]

If you prefer x-ticks to appear only on used x values:

```
h = plotyy(x-offset,y1,x+offset,y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{1}), @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{2}));
set(h,'xtick',x)
```