# Plotting bargraph with two y axes and multiple bars in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have three vectors m1, v1, and v2 all of equal length. Vector m1 has values in range [1000,10000] whereas v1 and v2 have values in range [1,2]. I want to plot a bar graph with all three vectors, but I want vectors v1 and v2 to use a smaller y-axis scale than m1. I have found multiple sources (e.g. [Matlab bar plot grouped but in different y scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688381/matlab-bar-plot-grouped-but-in-different-y-scales)) that recommend the following function for doing this with two vectors (m1, and v1)

```
plotyy(xrange-offset, m1, xrange+offset, v1, 'bar','bar')
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how to add v2 to this plot with the same scale as v1. Is there any way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each X,Y pair supplied as inputs to `plotyy` is treated as a separate input to the plotting function. That being said, it is definitely possible to generate multiple plots for the same y scale.

So `X1` and `Y1` (the first two inputs to `plotyy`) are the treated the same as passing two inputs to `bar` and accoriding to the documentation

> BAR(X,Y) draws the columns of the M-by-N matrix Y as M groups of N
>       vertical bars.  The vector X must not have duplicate values

The same format is also accepted for `X2` and `Y2` inputs to `plotyy`. So if you want to group `v1` and `v2` onto the same vertical scale you'll want to do something like the following.

```
plotyy(xrange - offset, m1, xrange + offset, [v1(:), v2(:)], 'bar', 'bar');
```

Comment: Yep, this solved it. Thanks! Some extra information for anyone looking at this question in the future: the colors and bar widths of all bars can be modified with the `set` command and the handles (`Ax,handle1,handle2 = plotyy(...)`)