# make bar plot with multiple y axis

Tags: matlab

I have some data I want to represent with a bar graph:

```
AAA=[2/3 1.5/3 .5/3 3; 1.5/3  1.8/3 .5/3 2.8];
figure
bar([1 2], AAA, 'BarWidth', 1)
```

[image]

But I would like to use one y-axis for the first three bars of each line of `AAA` and a different one for the fourth.

I could't use `plotyy` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688381/matlab-bar-plot-grouped-but-in-different-y-scales) because I have too many entries.

Do you know some alternatives?

Comment: If you have 2016a then you could use [`yyaxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html)

Comment: @Dan unfortunately I have 2014a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***WARNING:*** This solution does not generalize easily when you have different numbers of bars... a different method that generalized a bit better is presented at the end

From reading the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html), I don't see why `plotyy` wouldn't work (aside from being deprecated in favour of `yyaxis` in 2016a).

> plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,'function1','function2') uses function1(X1,Y1) to plot the data for the left axis and function2(X2,Y2) to plot the data for the right axis.

```
y1 = [2/3 1.5/3 .5/3; 1.5/3  1.8/3 .5/3];
y2 = [3; 2.8];
x = [1,2];
figure

% based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688381/matlab-bar-plot-grouped-but-in-different-y-scales
offset = (x(2)-x(1))/16; %needs to be generalised, so the 16 should be something like 2^(size(y1,2)+1) or 2^(size(y1,2)+size(y2,2))
width = (x(2)-x(1))/4; %The 4 here also needs to be generalized
colors = {'b','g'};
plotyy(x-offset*5,y1,x+offset*2,y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width*4,colors{1}), @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{2}));
```

[image]

But I would question whether or not it would be clearer to rather just use `subplot`

---

If you want to change the colours of the individual bars (per category that is), you have to do it manually:

```
h = plotyy(x-offset*5,y1,x+offset*2,y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width*4,colors{1}), @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{2}));
barGroup1 = h(1).Children;
map1 = [0, 0, 0.4;
        0, 0, 0.6;
        0, 0, 1];
for b = 1:numel(barGroup1)
    barGroup1(b).FaceColor = map1(b,:);
end
```

[image]

---

Another way to do this is instead of messing around with `offset` and `width` variables, just pad each `y` with a bunch of `0`s:

```
y1 = [2/3 1.5/3 .5/3,1; 1.5/3  1.8/3 .5/3,1;1,1,1,1];
y2 = [3,1; 2.8,1;1,1];
x = [1,2,4]; %x doesn't need to go up in increments of 1 (spacing will differ as you can see in the image), however it can only contain integers
nCol = max(size(y1,2),size(y2,2))*2;
Y1 = zeros(size(y1,1),nCol);
Y2 = zeros(size(y2,1),nCol);
% The idea is the make all the bars from group 1 sit before the group number (i.e. the numbers going from the halfway mark backwards) and all the bars from group 2 sit after the halfway mark (i.e. the numbers from the middle(+1) going forward)
Y1(:,nCol/2-size(y1,2)+1:nCol/2) = y1
Y2(:,nCol/2+1:nCol/2+1+size(y2,2)-1) = y2
h = plotyy(x,Y1,x,Y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,1,'b'), @(x,y) bar(x,y,1,'g'));
```

[image]

You can colour this chart the same way as above. This should generalize no matter the number of bars. Unfortunately you can't control the size of the gap between the groups.

Comment: @Dan Do you know how to specify the color of each bar? `colors = {'g','b','k','r'};` and 
`plotyy(x-offset*5,y1,x+offset*2,y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width*4,colors{1:3}),@(x,y) bar(x,y,width,colors{4}));
` doesn't quite work

Comment: @A_C It is common courtesy to upvote as well as accepting to maximise a user's effort.

Comment: @kkuilla Acceppting an answer gives already many reputation points. I usually upvote if the answer adds more than what the question demands. I think it is up to other users to upvote an answer. Of course I would upvote other answer other than the accepted one. I think it is quite fair.

Comment: @A_C see the edit regarding the colours. What still needs to be done is generalizing the `offset` and `width` and their multipliers to be based on the number of bars

Comment: @A_C To add on what Adriaan says: people in SO make an effort (a huge one this time, this answer is quite complete) to help you *for free*. Giving someone that made a huge effort to help you 10 imaginary points its something called *being polite and grateful*. Of course, you are free to do as you wish, no need of being grateful.

Comment: In this case I'll upvote beause Dan added something I asked before. But in general I still think that upvote+accepting makes a too big difference between the accepted answer and the other ones. Also because many times the fact of accepting an answer rather than another one is just matter of personal preference or timing. The difference in points between accepting and upvoting for me is what Adriaan calls "helping the most"

Comment: also as @Adriaan says " Normally upvotes are much more of a measure of how good an answer is than an accept". It is thus logic that upvoting should be a prerogative of users different from who asks the question.

Comment: @A_C when 3 people answered similar things and you can only accept, one, instead of not upvoting any, why not upvote all? There is no limit in being grateful.

Comment: @Adriaan and Ander Biguri then why  does acceptance give more points than upvote? For me the usefulness to the who asked the question should be reflected by a really slight difference in reputation points gain. For me, if I upvote AND accept the difference is too big.

Comment: Guys, if this really bothers you then maybe take it to meta. But this comment thread isn't useful to this answer or anyone coming later to view it.Thanks for the support though:)