# How to plot 2 bar graphs with independent y-axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Basically, I want a `plotyy` with bar graphs on columns 2 and 3 of a matrix `cat`, with the x-axis being column 1 of `cat`.

When I use the `bar` command, this is what I get:

```
bar(cat(:,2:3))
```

[image]

**This is the graph I want, but I also want another independent y-axis on the right side for the red coloured bars.**

When I use `plotyy` with the attribute`bar`, I get a wrong graph:

```
plotyy(cat(:,1),bar(cat(:,2)),cat(:,1),bar(cat(:,3)),'bar')
```

[image]

And when I use `bar` inside `plotyy`, I get only a few tiny dots:

```
plotyy(cat(:,1),bar(cat(:,2)), cat(:,1),bar(cat(:,3)))
```

[image]

So, what do I need to do?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785053/make-bar-plot-with-multiple-y-axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785053/make-bar-plot-with-multiple-y-axis)